# What should be done with suggested edits on posts that are likely to be removed?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Every now and again an edit will appear in the Suggested Edit queue that is on an answer that I've already seen in the Close Votes queue and I'm reasonably sure will be closed when enough people have got the time to vote.

In some cases they do improve the post (e.g. readability, grammar, formatting)... although the post still should be removed (e.g. it's still another question posted as an answer).

My question is, what should I do with these?

None of the rejection reasons really match up with "This post is clearly rubbish and shouldn't exist in the first place" so I tend to just skip them (naughty, I know).

It's happened a few times in the last few days though, so what is the proper etiquette?

Should I approve them because technically they do improve the "answer" (this feels wrong to me)? Should I just reject them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reject them or skip them, if they're edits to an obviously doomed question (such as "why does my PC beep when I turn it on?" then there's no harm at all in skipping them.

As a mod when I review the close queue it's tricky: if I agree it should be closed and say so it closes there and then, sometimes I prefer to get community input so in that case I have to skip.